# Discord.PY Button UI interaction fails after restart

Tags: python, button, discord.py, interaction

So i've been trying to get this discord button to work. And it does, kinda...
The button works as it's supposed to. But after a restart, the button looses all functionality and says "interaction failed" when clicking on it. This means i'd have to send the button again every time i restart the bot.

```
import discord
import config
import discord.ui
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, intents=intents, help_command=None)

class VerifyButton(discord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='verify_button')
    async def click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button):

        role = config.ROLE

        if config.ROLE in [y.id for y in interaction.user.roles]:
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(interaction.user.guild.get_role(role))
            await interaction.response.send_message("You've unverified yourself", ephemeral = True)

        else:
            await interaction.user.add_roles(interaction.user.guild.get_role(role))
            await interaction.response.send_message("You've been verified", ephemeral = True)

class VerifyViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, intents=intents)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.add_view(VerifyButton())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Successfully logged in as {client.user}')

    bot.add_view(VerifyButton())
    await bot.setup_hook()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith(f'{config.PREFIX}verify'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verify!", description="Read the rule, and press the button to Verify!")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed, view=VerifyButton())
```

When running the code in windows, there's no issues and the button will still work after the bot has been restarted.

Linux/Mac however does not work after a restart. I personally don't get why it behaves differently considering it's still python.

I'm aware that you need a persistent for it to persist between restarts. Which I do have, but only works in windows.

Comment: You are not using your `VerifyViewBot` subclass of `commands.Bot` when initializing your bot.

Answer (score 2):

You have **3** different types of clients here, and you're mixing them for some reason. You should only ever have **1**.

- `client = discord.Client(...)`: this is a `Client` instance and has no `Bot` functionality
- `bot = commands.Bot(...)`: this is a `Bot`
- Your `VerifyViewBot`: this is your own subclass, but you're never using it anywhere

Your `on_ready` is registered to `client`, but for some reason you're calling `bot.setup_hook` inside of it. `client` and `bot` are two different variables, and two different instances of two different classes. This doesn't make any sense.

Furthermore, `bot.setup_hook` doesn't do anything, because this is the default (empty) `setup_hook` method.

Create an instance of your **own** subclass, and register all event listeners to *that*. Also, **don't manually call `setup_hook`**, the library does it for you.

**Get rid of `client` and `bot`. You don't need them for anything. You've got your own subclass that you can use.**

As for persistent views, there's an official example you can follow: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

Lastly, you're using a `commands.Bot`, so you have access to commands. There's no point in manually parsing message content in an `on_message`, just use the `commands` framework that does this for you.